# How do I upgrade all upgradable packages using ppm?

Tags: perl, upgrade

When I open up `ppm`, the UI shows me several upgradable packages. Unfortunately, I cannot select them all by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> or clicking the first element, holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then select the last element in the list.

Do I **really** have to walk through all elements and press the <kbd>+</kbd> key in order to select them? Refusing to believe that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do it from the command line.

```
C:\>ppm upgrade --install
```

This will upgrade all packages without asking. There's something about it in the [Activestate online doc](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/bin/ppm.html).

Comment: It is now doing that for me for like 60 packages, which I wasn't really sure I wanted to upgrade. But it works. :)

Comment: It's still running... I wonder if this is going to break anything for me. :D Good thing is, I only use the Windows Perl installation for quick testing of scrap code.

Comment: I just upgraded my ActiveState installation and can confirm that it **will** terminate after upgrading :-)

Comment: It finally did, but took some time. Now I only need to find out how to update the actual Active Perl installation from 5.12 to 5.14.

Comment: if you're not sure whether to upgrade or not: I guess you could get a list of upgradable packages using only `ppm upgrade`. If you pipe that into a file and select those you want to install, I assume you could do a `ppm upgrade <package>` after editing the file and feeding each line as `<package>`...

Comment: Works well but be warned, it can take over an hour to complete.

Comment: @MatthewLock It's much faster if you disable HTML generation (see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=758733 )